# DockerCompose build one image and run multiple containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file which builds 4 images and runs 4 containers which is fine. But in those 4 Dockerfile which I used to build 4 images, the only difference is that the cmd. I'm just wondering if there's a better way of doing this like build one image and run 4 containers from that image just by changing the cmd,

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  esg_scoring.insight:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: insight/Dockerfile
  esg_scoring.momentum:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: momentum/Dockerfile
  esg_scoring.pulse:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: pulse/Dockerfile
  esg_scoring.sasb_mapping:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: sasb_mapping/Dockerfile
```

Comment: That's fine, and you can override the `command:` in the `docker-compose.yml` file.  (The most likely examples I can think of off hand involve running Celery workers against Python Django projects, but if you find one of those, the same technique will work in any language.)  Is there a specific problem you're encountering setting this up?

Comment: You mean like below. This works too. This actually helps to avoid writing multiple dockerfiles.But Can I avoid that build in every step instead can I refer the image built in the first step 

version: '3.6'

services:
  esg_scoring.insight:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: insight/Dockerfile
  esg_scoring.momentum:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: insight/Dockerfile
    command: /momentum_runner.py

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case you need multiple containers running the same image, and differing only by the command that starts them, you should most definitely avoid multiple docker images, and use the same image.

The [`command`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command) directive in `docker-compose` is what you are looking for.

In addition, you can use the YAML anchors syntax to reuse code blocks and simplify your code.

Here is an example of having 4 services, using the same image, with different commands. You can put all the arguments that are common to all, under the `default` setting:

```yaml
services:
  bash:
    build: .
    command: bash
    <<: &default
      image: me/my-image

  web:
    <<: *default
    command: bundle exec run server start

  setup:
    <<: *default
    command: bundle exec run db setup

  jobs:
    <<: *default
    command: bundle exec run job runner
```

The nice thing about this approach, is that it will only build once when you run `docker-compose build`, since the `build` directive is outside of the `default` setting.

Comment: Will it create four independent containers?

Comment: Yes, as long as you use `docker compose`, each service is its own container. In the example above, there will be four containers each spun up from the `me/my-image` image.